# Passing Textbox information from one form to another

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I'm trying to type a name (NameFirst)+(NameLast) store it in StudentName and transfer to the default form NameForm and then have that information displayed in StudentName once the submit button is pressed. The submit button also opens the main form, "frmMain"

I'm doing something wrong, obviously, as the StudentName textbox on the frmMain which is opened after pressing submit, is blank.

**NameForm**

```
Public Class NameForm

  Public StudentName As String

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


        StudentName = (NameFirst.Text) + (NameLast.Text)

        Dim openForm As frmMain
        openForm = New frmMain()
        openForm.Show()
        openForm = Nothing


    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonClear.Click
        NameFirst.Text = ""
        NameLast.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

**frmMain**

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off



Public Class frmMain



    Private Sub ButtonCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonCalc.Click

        Dim SumForum As Integer
        Dim SumAssign As Integer
        Dim FAverage As Double
        Dim AAverage As Double

        Dim Grades() As String = {"A", "A-", "B+", "B", "B-", "C+", "C", "C-", "D+", "D", "D-", "F"}


        'Total and then average of Forum grades, displayed in Forum Average text box
        SumForum = CInt(Val(Forum1.Text) + Val(Forum2.Text) + Val(Forum3.Text) + Val(Forum4.Text) + Val(Forum5.Text) + Val(Forum6.Text) + Val(Forum7.Text) + Val(Forum8.Text))

        FAverage = (SumForum / 8)

        ForumAverage.Text = CStr((FAverage))


        'Total and then average of Assignment grades, displayed in Assignment Average text box
        SumAssign = CInt(Val(Assign1.Text) + Val(Assign2.Text) + Val(Assign3.Text) + Val(Assign4.Text) + Val(Assign5.Text) + Val(Assign6.Text) + Val(Assign7.Text) + Val(Assign8.Text))

        AAverage = (SumAssign / 8)

        AssignAverage.Text = CStr(AAverage)

    End Sub




    Private Sub ButtonExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub



    Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        NameForm.StudentName = Me.StuName.Text
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: But, you have name form creating an instance of mainform...

Comment: OK...what should I be doing?

Comment: Well according to your question mainform wants to pass to NameForm...

Comment: Where/How are you displaying NameForm?  I think frmMain displays NameForm, as that would make sense, but it's not entirely clear from the code.  Just display your instance of NameForm with ShowDialog(), then retrieve the value using the reference you've already got.

Comment: NameForm opens first, name is typed, click submit, frmMain opens. I don't know why the name has to be on another form, which is the first, with the grade form opening next. Just the way it was assigned.

Comment: Which Form is set as the "Startup object" in Project --> Properties?

Comment: I changed the startup to frmMain just now. So when you click in the StudentName box on frmMain, the NameForm opens and the name can be entered there. Though getting the name from NameForm to frmMain is still perplexing me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I changed the startup to frmMain just now. So when you click in the
>   StudentName box on frmMain, the NameForm opens and the name can be
>   entered there. Though getting the name from NameForm to frmMain is
>   still perplexing me

Great.  In frmMain, you'd do something like this:

```
Dim nf As New NameForm
If nf.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then ' <-- code stops here until "nf" is dismissed
    Me.StuName.Text = nf.StudentName
End If
```

Over in NameForm, once you set your StudentName field, you simply set DialogResult to OK:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    StudentName = NameFirst.Text & NameLast.Text
    Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK ' <-- returns execution back to frmMain
End Sub
```

Comment: Course creating the dialog should be in a using block. Name would appear to be a structure, and directly coupling forms like this is a really bad idea.

Comment: Ah, I see the Show Dialog was confusing me after the change. Thank you. So the nf.ShowDialog section brings up the NameForm, once the information has been entered the Me.StuName area transfers it back to the frmMain. Correct?

Comment: In this approach, nothing goes "back" to frmMain since you are already **in** frmMain.  A better explanation would be that once an "OK" is returned from NameForm, frmMain retrieves the entered value.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, How are they directly coupled?  With the changes I made, NameForm has no knowledge of frmMain thus making it loosely coupled.  The original approach by the author was definitely tightly coupled and not the way I would do it.

Comment: That's correct.  Though in this case I don't think it's particularly vital.  You're not going to be doing a high volume of manual entries.  The instance of NameForm you create will get properly disposed of eventually by the garbage collector anyways.

Comment: Dim nf as new Nameform is a direct coupling. Doubt it's a problematic one in this case, but throw in say address, telephone, email, etc, this approach gets messy quick.